# Unable to download an image in android

Tags: android, httpclient, twitter-oauth, sslexception

I need to download twitter profile picture of mine and show it in an imageview on click of a button. Here is my code to download the profile picture of desired user.

```
public static InputStream getTwitterProfilePictureOfUser(String twitterId){
    try {
        return new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?user_id="+twitterId+"&size=bigger")).getEntity().getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Getting the following exceptions. Where i'am going wrong ?

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:371)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:92)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:381)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:174)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
at com.tarams.android.giveblood.service.ServiceStub.getTwitterProfilePictureOfUser(ServiceStub.java:207)
    at com.tarams.android.giveblood.activities.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:128)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor for CertPath not found.
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:168)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:366)
... 24 more
 Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor for CertPath not found.
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.java:149)
at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:202)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:164)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to connect to an HTTPS URL via and the SSL certificate provided by the site is not trusted by the devise you are running the code on. I suggest you read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https) on setting up trust in the Apache HTTP Client